# Breaking on exception: type 'Shaders' is not a subtype of type 'Shaders' of 's'. What?

Tags: webgl, dart

I like Dart, so I've been writing a small WebGL game. I have a `Shaders` class which is pretty basic:

```dart
class Shaders {
  static final int FRAGMENT = 0;
  static final int VERTEX = 1;

  HashMap<String, webGL.UniformLocation> _uniforms;

  webGL.Program           _program;
  webGL.Shader            _vertShader;
  webGL.Shader            _fragShader;
  webGL.RenderingContext  _gl;


  Shaders(this._gl) {
    _uniforms = new HashMap();
    _program = _gl.createProgram();
    _vertShader = _gl.createShader(webGL.VERTEX_SHADER);
    _fragShader = _gl.createShader(webGL.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  }

  Future<String> loadSource(String filename) {
    return HttpRequest.getString(filename);
  }

  void compileSource(int type, String data) {
    if (type == VERTEX) {
      _gl.shaderSource(_vertShader, data);
      _gl.compileShader(_vertShader);
      _gl.attachShader(_program, _vertShader);

      if (!_gl.getShaderParameter(_vertShader, webGL.COMPILE_STATUS))
          print("Vertex shader: ${_gl.getShaderInfoLog(_vertShader)}");

    } else if (type == FRAGMENT) {
      _gl.shaderSource(_fragShader, data);
      _gl.compileShader(_fragShader);
      _gl.attachShader(_program, _fragShader);

      if (!_gl.getShaderParameter(_fragShader, webGL.COMPILE_STATUS))
          print("Vertex shader: ${_gl.getShaderInfoLog(_fragShader)}");
    }
  }

  void setUniformMatrix(String name, var mat) {
    //if we dont have this uniform get it and store for later
    if (!_uniforms.containsKey(name)) {
      var loc = _gl.getUniformLocation(_program, name);
      _uniforms[name] = loc;
    }

    _gl.uniformMatrix4fv(_uniforms[name], false, mat.data());
  }

  void bindAttribute(int index, String name) {
    _gl.bindAttribLocation(_program, index, name);
  }

  void useShader() {
    _gl.linkProgram(_program);
    _gl.useProgram(_program);
  }
}
```

I also have a `RenderComponent` class that I give to entities when they should be drawable. 
It looks like this (these classes aren't done):

```dart
abstract class Component {
  static final int RENDER = 1;
  int _type;

  Component(this._type);  
  int get type => _type;
}


class RenderComponent extends Component {
  BufferObject _vbo;
  Shaders _shader;

  RenderComponent() : super(Component.RENDER);

  set shader(Shaders s) => _shader = s;
  set buffer(BufferObject v) => _vbo = v;

  Shaders get shader           => _shader;
  BufferObject get buffer      => _vbo;
}
```

When I create an object of `RenderComponent` and set the `shader` like this:

```dart
var s = new Shaders(pass in gl context);
var r = new RenderComponent();

r.shader = s;
```

I get this error message:

```
Breaking on exception: type 'Shaders' is not a subtype of type 'Shaders' of 's'.
```

Google didn't come up with anything that makes sense to me. This is the most unhelpful message I've ever come across, and I can't get past it. Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: There are some confusing inconsistencies: `Shaders` vs. `Shader`, `shader` vs. `shade`.

Comment: sorry just a typo in the post

Comment: Alright, next try: Are there multiple classes called `Shaders`, in different libraries maybe? Might be a simple name conflict.

Comment: i thought of that, no i even changed the name of this shaders class to something crazy like ShadersABCD same error message.

Comment: Let's dig deeper - SDK version? Dartium launch or JS launch? I used your code (slightly modified to prevent warnings/errors) and it works without this error. Also, use @MarioP to answer, so I get a notification ;)

Comment: @MarioP ok, Dart Editor version 0.5.20_r24160, Dart SDK version 0.5.20.2_r24160 and running in dartium no JS launch. if its working for you maybe i should create a new project and try it there, see if that makes any changes. Thanks for you help by the way.

Comment: I don't think this is the reason. There has to be something not reflected in your posted code. Does it work for you if you just copy your own code? For reference, I deleted everything concerning the BufferObject, removed the lines in `Shaders` constructor and passed `null` to it. No runtime errors.

Comment: I got it working, when you said it worked for you then i stopped looking at the code and how i was defining my libraries. i have it working, i guess i need to reread desinging your own libraries when writing large projects. Thanks @MarioP

Comment: Could you post the answer? Could help later users with the same problem. Also, now I'm curious ;-)